# Joining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, inner-join, join

I am trying to join a dataofbirth column which is in studentdetails table with another table called college table, I need the dataofbirth of the student in the second table.Here is my query.

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `DateofBirth` FROM  `studentdetails` INNER JOIN `college`
   ON `studentdetails`.StudentID = college.StudentID")or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con)");
```

So when I fetch my array for the second table I would be able to get their dataofBirth of student without joining them physically.
Can anyone spot what's wrong with my syntax ?

Thank you

Comment: Why its not working, is the result array empty or does mysqli throw and print an error? If its the case please enlight us and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Which table contains dateofbirth? As per above its in both the tables? Can you paste the schema and sample data in it?

Comment: @Steini NO it is only syntax errors with myphp can you spots what's wrong with my syntax apart from mysql query inside PHP

Comment: DateofBirth is present in which table or both ?

Comment: @almasshaikh dateofbirth only exists in the studentdetails where actually I need the dataofbirth in the second table which is college table

Comment: @CodingAnt dateofbirth only exists in one table studentdetails table

Comment: You query is fine what's wrong now? Which syntax are you talking about?

Comment: The clue is in the error message

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join two tables you have to provide the list of columns from both tables that you want to be included in joined/combined table. So:

Try this (substituting [add other columns..] bit with the other columns you might want to include. And take note of the table aliases how they are being used:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT s.DateofBirth, c.StudentID, [add other columns from college table here...] FROM  studentdetails sd INNER JOIN college c
   ON sd.StudentID = c.StudentID")or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con)");
```

oh and you might want to use mysqli instead of old, deprecated, ugly, slow, insecure, suicidal thoughts inducing mysql_ extension ;)

Comment: @Jaek.D I got error saying undefined StudentID so I edited the code as  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT s.DateofBirth, c.StudentID FROM  studentdetails sd INNER JOIN college c
   ON sd.StudentID = c.StudentID WHERE StudentID  = '" . $_SESSION['StudentID'] . "'")or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con)"); and I got another error Error: Column 'StudentID' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: in what table your StudentID column actually exists? if in college table you shoud do 'WHERE c.StudentID' if in studentdetails then WHERE sd.StudentID'.  in short you have to qualify the column name with a table alias to be unambigiuous

Comment: StudentID exists in both of them since it is primary key.

Comment: I echo $row[DateofBirth]; so I may see the date of birth afer joining both tables but still nothing showing up.

Comment: StudentID exists in both tables since it is a primary key.

Comment: "SELECT s.DateofBirth, c.StudentID FROM studentdetails sd INNER JOIN college c ON sd.StudentID = c.StudentID WHERE StudentID = " . (int)$_SESSION['StudentID']

Comment: by using apostrophes you ID from session is treated as string and it should be int most likely

Answer (score 0):

It should be (from the comment : **dateofbirth** only exists in the studentdetails )

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sd.DateofBirth FROM  studentdetails as sd INNER JOIN college as c
    ON sd.StudentID = c.StudentID")or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con)");
```

Comment: aliases for the table name , (eg --> studentdetails as sd)

Comment: I got error saying undefined StudentID so I edited the code as $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT s.DateofBirth, c.StudentID FROM studentdetails sd INNER JOIN college c ON sd.StudentID = c.StudentID WHERE StudentID = '" . $_SESSION['StudentID'] . "'")or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con)"); and I got another error Error: Column 'StudentID' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @ZinaDweeikat use my above query , dont edit it .It will be a success :) , your query is still wrong

Comment: I used your code and I have no errors but still I am not getting any data. :(

Answer (score 0):

Considering that we born only once (except for phoenixes) the relationship between students and their date of birth is supposed to be `1:1` relationship. In other words, column `DateOfBirth` could be declared in `college` table. Then to select their date of birth you simple could do:

```
select DateOfBirth
from   college
where  StudentID = :id
```

But I see you already have another table to store their date of birth so you could do a join to select their date of birth:

```
select d.DateOfBirth
from   college        c,
       studentdetails d
where  c.StudentID = d.StudentID;
```

Or:

```
select d.DateofBirth 
from   studentdetails d
inner join college as c
   on d.StudentID = c.StudentID;
```

But this queries above would exclude the students without records in `studentdetails` from your result. To select all students with their respective date of birth you could do:

```
select c.StudentID, 
       s.DateOfBirth
from   studentdetails d
right join college c
      on d.StudentID = c.StudentID;
```

This `right join` query gets all the students even if they don't have a date of birth in `studentdetails` table (`right join` cmd on table college).

You're free to figure out what's the best alternative to you, but I recommend you to normalize this data model putting column `DateOfBirth` inside `college` table.

Comment: Here is my query $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT s.DateofBirth, c.StudentID FROM studentdetails sd INNER JOIN college c ON sd.StudentID = c.StudentID WHERE StudentID = '" . $_SESSION['StudentID'] . "'")or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con)"); but still getting this error -  Error: Column 'StudentID' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: DateofBirth only declared in one table which is studentdetails

Comment: @ZinaDweeikat concatenating SQL queries is really, really bad practice. Please, learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: There are two syntax erros in this query. You're selecting `s.DateOfBirth` but you named `studentdetails` table as `sd`. Second is that you have `StudentID` column in both tables so you need to specify wich `StudentID` you're referencing in where clause (i.e. `...where c.StudentID = ". $_SESSION...`).